# Creating Multiple Sheets in Google Sheets w/Loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to put together this code that will create multiple sheets that I will eventually be putting data on.

Here is what I have:

```
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet_names_to_create = ["blah1", "blah2", "blah3", "blah4", "blah5", "blah6", "blah7", "blah8"]
  for (var i = 0; i < sheet_names_to_create.length; i++) {
    if(activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet_names_to_create[i]) == null){
      var newSht = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();//Create new Sheet
      newSht.setName(sheet_names_to_create[i]);
    }
  }
```

The issue is that I ran it the first time and saw no added sheets. I ran it the second time and it says the sheet name already exists.

What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

Comment: You might want to put SpreadsheetApp.flush() between creating the sheet and renaming it.  Or do as I did in my answer name it when you create it. It takes time to create a sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create Sheets**

```
 function hisfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sA=["blah1", "blah2"]
  sA.forEach(function(s,i){var sh=ss.getSheetByName(s);if(!sh){ss.insertSheet(s);}else{sh.clearContents();}});
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out using my code, but this is SO much cleaner. I have a lot to learn. One more thing though. On the If statement I'd like to add that if it exists clear the content. Can you add that?

Comment: Saw the edit to add the clearing of content if sheet already exists. All is working great. Thanks.